# Organizing many texts by swapping instances

Tags: java, json, text, adventure

I am planning to develop an adventure-like game. 
For that I am going to have a lot of instances of classes with different texts (basicly strings).

I dont want to hardcode this many texts, so i am looking for a way to do it better.

The guy in this video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CDePunJlck ) is using json to write text files for each class instance manually and parse them automatically into instances. That goes into the right direction.

I´m looking for more information on that, so how is this procedure called? 
Its said in the video that this also works with databases?

Is there a way to design a little bit more complex stuff with things like this?

E.g. I have the case that I would like to output different texts if e.g. a local or global variable is over a treshold etc. Can I do this without hardcoding and write an own class for each of my proposed instances?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad, and it is hard to give a definitive answer. Here are some thoughts - hope you find it helpful.

You are right that you don't want to hardcode strings. The alternative to this is storing strings as external resources, and loading them into your game at start. There are numerous ways the resource can be organized; the choice depends on your programming platform, game architecture etc. For example, you can use simple name-value approach:

```
AREA_1_DESCRIPTION: You stand next o a small white house. 
ITEM_22_DESTRUCTION: The nasty snake disappears with a loud "Bang!"
```

Using JSON or XML will give you more structured storage, which can be of great help, since you can organize your texts so that it is easier to use them in the code:

```
<item id="375" name="Great Sword">
    <short_description>A Great Sword of Darkness</short_description>
    <long_description>The sword has almost black blade with some unknown runes engraved</long_description>
</item>
```

If your programming system can access a database, then you can do something similar and store texts in the tables; this, however, might make it more difficult to edit texts later. If you want to go this way, I would still recommend using XML or JSON to store the texts, and making the game import texts in DB on the first run.

You probably will also need some sort of simple template-handling engine to be able to re-use some strings. You can start with creating your version of Java String.format() method. Your method might take as a first argument an ID of a string in your string catalog, and use some simple placeholders for the parameters. Suppose you have the following entry in your catalog:

```
FIRE_GEM_ACTION: "The Fire Gem touches %% and in %% seconds it turns into ashes."
```

Then you can write a method that will do something like this:

```
int delaySeconds = 5;
String message = MyTemplateProcessor.process(FIRE_GEM_ACTION, "old map", delaySeconds);
```

The function will take the string from the catalog, search for the occurrences of the placeholders (%%) and replace them sequentially with the parameters, so in the message you will get: The Fire Gem touches old map and in 5 seconds it turns into ashes.

In general, I would recommend you to have a look at some systems specially designed for creation of adventure games. Inform 7 will be a good starting place: http://inform7.com/learn/

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!

Inform7 seems to be an own development environment, am I right?
I cant use this because I want to develop an Android App, so i am not that flexible.

I think what is interesting for me is the template handling. Can I realize the following with a more complex template-handling?

I need to be able to fill in different texts depending on the values of different variables. I am looking for some concepts to do this. 

I wrote an example for this in my main post.

I hope my concern is a little clearer now.

Comment: Inform is a separate language, and I suggested it not as a development tool for making Android apps, but as a reference of some of the approaches in making text adventure games.

Comment: @Programmer879, I've added some suggestions about the templates to the answer

Comment: Thank you again. :)
What would I do if i had a long description for an item, e.g. a text with 7 sentences. And depending on the value of a variable one sentence changes. The value of the variable is only known at runtime. I would like to define the alternative versions of this sentence in the xml etc.

Comment: You can do it the same way - replace a placeholder with an entire sentence.